# Broadcast Receiver is not receiveing the intent data in android.Looking for Solution

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send intent data to `MainActivity`.And i'm receiving the data from `GCM Server`, that received data I want to send to my `MainActivity`.

**In GcmBroadcastReceiver Class**

```
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
      GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Intent i = new Intent("CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED");
    i.putExtra("Message", extras.getString("Message"));
    i.putExtra("Sender",extras.getString("Sender"));
    i.putExtra("Receiver",extras.getString("Receiver"));
    i.putExtra("Calltype",extras.getString("calltype"));
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

These above code I am using to receive the data from `GCM Sever` and also use the `BroadcastReceiver` to send data.

**In MainActivity Class**

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,newIntentFilter("CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"));
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {           
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        String message = b.getString("Message");
        String sender=b.getString("Sender");
        String receiver=b.getString("Receiver");
    }
};
```

In activity I have used the broadcast receiver to receive the intent with data.

Comment: In GCM Broadcast Receiver:

Comment: Make your question clear

Comment: without seeing some code, crash report or something else that is more clear, You will get no help here.....that´s not a forum for clairvoyants....

Comment: i am developing the Chatting app , if i will receive the message from GCM server ,that received message i want to send to activity @Jas

Comment: Please help me i don't know how do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your GcmListenerService # onMessageRecieved() function use this code
 Intent intent = new Intent(ANY_TAG);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

AND in your activity use following code

 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            displayToast(" Data received");
        }
    };

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getContext().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(ANY_TAG));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: tyr it when app is open.

Comment: sorry typo . try it when app is open

Comment: there may be some brackets missing but it should work as i am using currently in same way

Comment: No .I am using Broadcast Receiver in Activity only ..Then How can i add in Manifest file?? @Khizar Hayat

Comment: i am asking about service tag for GcmListenerService , MyInstanceIDListenerService and RegistrationIntentService. And receiver tag for com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver

Comment: ya .. that mentioned in Manifest file..@Khizar Hayat...i am receiving from Gcm Server but that received message i cant send to Activity.

Comment: Hmm. weird. above code is working perfect in my app. best wishes for you :)

Comment: Its Working..@Khizar Hayat

Answer (score 1):

// Use observable object as an interface

```
public class ObservableObject extends Observable {
private static ObservableObject instance = new ObservableObject();

public static ObservableObject getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private ObservableObject() {
}

public void updateValue(Object data) {
    synchronized (this) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(data);
    }
}
}
```

// MainRecevier

```
public class MainReceiver extends        BroadcastReceiver 
 {
public final static String MAINRECEIVERSETALARM="ir.shes.schedule.MainReceiver.setalarm";
public final static String MAINRECEIVERSNOOZE="ir.shes.schedule.MainReceiver.snooze";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context p1, Intent p2)
{

    ObservableObject.getInstance().updateValue(p2);

}


}
```

// MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Observer 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ObservableObject.getInstance().addObserver(this);
}
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {        

    String action=((Intent)data).getAction();
    if (action.equals(MainReceiver.MAINRECEIVERSETALARM))
        app.eventCache.setAlarm();
    if (action.equals(MainReceiver.MAINRECEIVERSNOOZE))
        Toast.makeText(this, "snooze", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

// static register receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="ir.shes.schedule.MainReceiver">
        <intent-filter>     

            <action android:name="ir.shes.schedule.MainReceiver.setalarm" />
            <action android:name="ir.shes.schedule.MainReceiver.snooze" />

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you have declared the BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadCastReceiver" />
```

Comment: No . I am using Broadcast Receiver in activity.@Dm